# R loop through association rule mining (arules) with changing supports and item appearances

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, data-mining, arules

fairly new to R here. I am looking to mine association rules in R for specific items, but I want to vary the minimum support target for these rules by each item (i.e. 10% of the **item's** total frequency in the transaction list). Each item has a different amount of transactions so I believe there is value in varying the support.

I've calculated the support targets for each item in a separate spreadsheet using Excel.

I can do this manually writing the arules code and manually inputting support minimum and item appearances, but the process is slow, especially with many different items.

ex.

```
arules <- apriori(trans, parameter = list(sup = 0.001, conf = 0.25,target="rules"), 
    appearance=list(rhs= c("Apples")))
arules2 <- apriori(trans, parameter = list(sup = 0.002, conf = 0.25,target="rules"), 
    appearance=list(rhs= c("Oranges")))
combined <- c(arules,arules2)
```

How can I do this using a for loop in R that will calculate the rules for each specified item at a specific support minimum, and also save those generated rules to a new variable each time the loop runs? I intend to later group these rules depending on their type.

Tried something like this which looped through too many times. I also couldn't figure out a way to save each loop to a new variable (i.e. arules1, arules2, arules3....)

```
min_supp <- c(0.001,0.002,0.003)
names <- c("Apples","Oranges","Grape")

for (inames in names) {
    for (supports in min_supp) {
        apriori(trans, parameter = list(sup = supports, conf = 0.25,target="rules"),
        appearance=list(rhs= inames))
        }}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider `Map` (the simplified wrapper to `mapply`) that can iterate elementwise through same length vectors for a **m**ultiple **apply** method. Additionally, `Map` will output a list of the returned items which can be named with `setNames`. Lists are always preferred as you avoid separate, similarly structured objects flooding global environment.

```
min_supp <- c(0.001,0.002,0.003)
names <- c("Apples","Oranges","Grape")

arules_fun <- function(n, s) apriori(trans, parameter = list(sup = s, conf = 0.25, target="rules"), 
                                     appearance=list(rhs= n))

# PROCESS FUNCTION ELEMENTWISE 
arules_list <- Map(arules_fun, names, min_supp)    
# NAME LIST ITEMS
arules_list <- setNames(arules_list, paste0("arules", 1:length(arules_list)))

arules_list$arules1
arules_list$arules2
arules_list$arules3
...
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you for teaching me some new things

Comment: Hi again @Parfait, Is there any loop or function that allows me to call all arules_list$arules1, arules_list$arules2.. items at once. I'd like to combine them all using the c(arules_list$arules1, arules_list$arules2).

Tried test <- Reduce(merge, arules_list)
but got: Error in as.data.frame.default(x) : 
  cannot coerce class "structure("rules", package = "arules")" to a data.frame

Comment: Try do.call: `do.call(c, arules_list)`.

Comment: Gave me this error:
`Error in (function (n, s)  : 
  unused arguments (arules1 = <S4 object of class "rules">, arules2 = <S4 object of class "rules">, arules3 = <S4 object of class "rules">, arules4 = <S4 object of class "rules"> ....`

Comment: What type is the return of `apriori()`? Matrix? Dataframe?

Comment: returns the s4 object of class rules that can be changed to a dataframe with the function DATAFRAME(arules), not a matrix

Comment: Try: `do.call(rbind, arules_list)`

Comment: Got: `Error in rep(argl[[na]], length.out = nr) : 
  attempt to replicate an object of type 'S4'` I already know the number of lists that will be generated from earlier, so perhaps something similar to            c(arules_list$arules[i]....) where that repeats through 1:14 might work? Im not really sure how to code that though

Comment: Please show the output of one of the *arules_list* by editing your post.